# Can you bypass a rack mounted house EQ if you have a good sound board?

Tags: equalization, equipment

Sound noob here; We have an OLD (~40 yrs...) sound rack in our Community Theatre, it has two rack Mounted EQ, one for L one for R, but one of them has died and doesn't do anything. Our Community Theatre has a newer Behringer X32, which has a lot of EQ functionality.

My question is if we're using an X32 do we even need the old EQ in the rack? Could I just bypass it/junk it and adjust EQ for the room on the board?

Answer (score 3):

The idea of a 'fixed' FoH EQ is that it has supposedly been set up by a pro with sound analysis gear to ensure the response to the room is as flat as possible.

I reality, in many 'community' structures, unless it's actually locked away, it gets tweaked by someone different every week, because they think they can make it sound 'better'.
Once that's been done for a year or two, there's little semblance of the original curve, so it will need doing over from scratch.

The antithesis of that is it becomes like some kind of holy relic, to never be touched by anyone for fear of the wrath of 'the powers that be'. So over the years, someone buys new speakers or amps, but never changes the FoH EQ. It sits there like some ancient talisman whose true purpose is now long-forgotten, fixing an EQ which no longer exists; has completely changed since it was last set properly, because no-one dares touch it.

You're not going to be able to fully compensate for the room just using the board's EQ, but if the FoH EQ isn't tuned to the room precisely, then locked away, then frankly your guess is as good as mine as to whether it will sound better with it or without it.

You really ought to get the EQ fixed/replaced & have the room measured again; then lock it down.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The EQ is certainly locked down and bolted behind glass. It hasn't been touched for decades. I know the speakers have been swapped out at least once, and the House has changed some, but it changes every time Theatre does a show too, depending on how they set up the seat risers and build out the stage. It's a multi use facility that's used for everything from basketball tournaments to gymnastics, musical theatre and dances.  I have no idea what situation they made the room flat for, probably just an empty room.

Comment: The principal users of the facility are Community Theatre, in their case, after they've set up the house (gym floor) with the seating risers and the stage apron on front of the stage and thrust, loaded it full of chairs, and hug curtains everywhere, then they might need different EQ anyway eh? So maybe it would be be better to get a reference microphone and set the EQ with the board once the house is set up?

Comment: Hmm… you're kind of between a rock & a hard place. Whatever it was set for, the speakers have changed since… & the room's never the same twice. That kind of puts it in 'holy relic' territory - it was once useful for something, but no-one knows what that was any more. Then I shall have to invoke the 'your guess is as good as mine' get-out clause ;)) If budget will stretch to it - this would be a good time to buy a measurement system, so it can be usefully re-done for each run.